# How can I add a "&" to my url in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, url-routing

I have a database where I have an option to filter. With JSON, I want the filtering to work with JavaScript.

The problem I have now is that this is an example of the url when I filter:

```
index.php?action=page=activities&dayparts%5B%5D=2
```

I want it to be:

```
index.php?action=&page=activities&dayparts%5B%5D=2
```

This is the code I use:

```
const getActivities = async () => {
        const $form = document.getElementById('form--filter');
        console.log($form);
        const data = new FormData($form);
        const entries = [...data.entries()];
        console.log('entries:', entries);
        const qs = new URLSearchParams(entries).toString();
        console.log('querystring', qs);
        const url = `${$form.getAttribute('action')}?${qs}`;
        console.log('url', url);


        const response = await fetch(url, {
            headers: new Headers({
                Accept: 'application/json'
            })

        });

        const activities = await response.json();

        updateList(activities);
        console.log(activities);

        window.history.pushState({},
            '',
            `${window.location.href.split('?')[0]}?action=${qs}`
        );
    }
```

Is there a way I can add the **&** to the url?

Comment: Can't you simpy put it there `${window.location.href.split('?')[0]}?action=&${qs}` ?

Comment: Hi! I know you're relatively new to this site, so don't take it personally, but it's always best to only supply the code that is relevant to the problem. This includes removing all console logs, etc.

Comment: @obscure dang it, that I didn't see that myself, thank you!

Comment: @zfrisch Will do that next time!

Comment: Hehe no problem @FoxOnFireHD - glad I could help!